# Use of deleted function error occurs when the constructor of a class calls its member function?

Tags: c++

I have some work for the constructor to do,so I call a member function inside the constructor:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    class Token{
    public:
        Token() {}
        Token(const string &targetfile);
        void GetToken();
        ifstream in;
    };
    Token::Token(const string &targetfile)
    {
        in.open(targetfile);    
        GetToken();
    }
    void Token::GetToken()
    {
        in.close();
    }
    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        Token first = Token(string(argv[1]));
        return 0;
    }
```

I got error like this:

> use of deleted function ‘Token::Token(Token&&)’
>    note: ‘Token::Token(Token&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default       definition would be ill-formed

Comment: This compiles with g++: https://ideone.com/M4BAgN

Comment: I got error using:g++ -std=c++11 debug.cpp -o debug

Comment: Did you try different options? ideone.com uses C++14

Comment: I found that if I removed codes related with ifstream in then it would compile.But I don't know what's wrong with the file stream.

Comment: `std::fstream` and other stream classes can't be copied or assigned. The compiler can't generate a default assignment operator or copy constructor for other objects containing such a stream as a result of this. Either you define your own or live with not being able to copy or assign your type either. BTW: you could have answered your question yourself. It should have been pretty easy to find out whether a call to the memberfunction makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Token first(string(argv[1]));` instead of `Token first = Token(string(argv[1]));`

This way the extra move operator will not be called.

Comment: The `string` constructor is implicit, use `Token first(argv[1]);` instead.

Comment: @Dragos That's a function declaration.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It can be in another context, but in this one it is a variable declaration whith an explicit constructor.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt you are right. Thanks for the observation.